# Grid layout isn't show in ionic 1

Tags: layout, ionic-framework

I have this code in ionic and the problem is that the grid layout isn't showing and the side menu is working well, any help will be great.

```
<body>

<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content>

      <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="button icon button-clear ion-round"</button>          
        </div>

      </ion-header-bar>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-side-menu side="left"> 

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>About Us</ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>Contact Us</ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>Gallery</ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>News</ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>

<ion-content>
  <div class="row">    

    <div class="col-50"> Gallery</div>
  </div>
</ion-content>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you opening a new ion-list to every item? Shouldn't you just use one list and inserting the items you want in it?

This way can cause problems in the scroll, any kind of distribution you want to apply to the elements should be done by css.